# Radio Button On select or unselect Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i select the radio button then i want to hide one div and when i uncheck the radio button then i want to show that div . please if anyone know. I want to hide div on check the radio button.

```
<input type="radio" id="fix" name="price" checked="checked" value="fix">
<div id="hour">
<input type="text" name="rs"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Post your js code please.

Comment: The type should be `checkbox` not `radio`

Comment: I have no knowledge about javascript or jquery. ALek

Comment: No its radio button MR_green .

Comment: @VikasRana Once radio button is selected you can't unchecked it, until you refresh your page. What you are looking for is checkbox. Which can be checked and unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change() function from jQuery that triggers when the selector has been changed. Then just compare the val() with your value, and take action.

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "fix") {
        // show div
    } else {
        // hide div
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have single radio button you probably want to use checkbox instead. As single radio button could not be unchecked.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/TG8B6/1/)**

*Html*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="fix" name="price" checked="checked" value="fix">
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#fix').change(function(){
  $('[name=rs]')[0].style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't uncheck a radio button when there is only one.

So, change the input type to `checkbox`. Then you can use this CSS:

```
:checked + #hour{
    display: none;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVpbC/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "fix") {
        document.getElementById("hour").style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hour").style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Simple solution.